# strings.xml Managementtool

Tags: android, translation

I am looking for a tool to manage my `strings.xml` to localize String. The tool should show which string are missing in which translation.
The tool has to be free for commercial use. Is there something I could use?

My searches for a tool like that only showed up http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/motodevstudio/download/
But this seems to be not free for commercial use if i understood it right.

Comment: Could you not just use a text comparison tool? Since if a tag is missing the name="sameForEachLanguage" will be misaligned at the missing string position?

Answer (score 2):

[Lint](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint) is a tool included with the Android SDK (and is therefore free for all use, commercial or otherwise) and gives you a list of missing translations. It can be run in Eclipse, from the command line, and can generate HTML reports.

For, example, from the command line in your project's root directory:

```
lint --check MissingTranslation .
```

produces a list of all strings from any .xml file that is missing from one of the supported languages (denoted by at least one folder with a language suffix).

Answer (score 1):

You can try [XML Diff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx) from Microsoft. I'm not sure if you are allowed to use it commercially though (it doesn't say that you can't on the website).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the web service [Crowdin](https://crowdin.com). It will show which strings are left to translate, for which languages, with percentages.

Answer (score 0):

well.. I would do something like that -
say values/strings.xml is your master file
which has it all. then just run through it and 
compare to it the rest of the files....

`cd res`

`find . -name strings.xml -exec diff -u values\/strings.xml {} \;`

```
--- values/strings.xml  2013-04-30 00:42:46.000000000 -0400
+++ ./values-es/strings.xml 2013-04-30 00:42:03.000000000 -0400
@@ -1,6 +1,4 @@
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
-    <string name="app_name">frosty</string>
-    <string name="foo">Android</string>
-    <string name="bar">Android</string>
-</resources>
+    <string name="app_name">Brabble-Android</string>
+</resources>
\ No newline at end of file
--- values/strings.xml  2013-04-30 00:42:46.000000000 -0400
+++ ./values-fr/strings.xml 2013-04-30 00:49:16.000000000 -0400
@@ -1,6 +1,5 @@
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
     <string name="app_name">frosty</string>
-    <string name="foo">Android</string>
-    <string name="bar">Android</string>
+    <string name="foo">bar</string>
 </resources>
```

that should be a part of it at least.

---

hope it helps abit.